# Genesis Child Theme - Customize body

Tags: plugins, themes, child-theme

So I created a custom post type and I've also created a custom page called `page-profile.php` that follows the WordPress templating.

Here is the code inside  `page-profile.php`:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'profile', // enter custom post type
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);

get_header(); // displays header
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); //displays footer
```

So the header, footer and sidebar all are being called in.

How can I target the red box and create templating where I would like to show the title and thumbnail?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`the Loop`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/) to your template to display post content.

Regular loop (the current page).

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <article>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php // Navigation ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <?php // No Posts Found ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Custom query loop. Notice the [`wp_rest_postdata()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/)

```
<?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <article>
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

  <!-- reset global post variable. After this point, we are back to the Main Query object -->
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php // No Posts Found ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

You can also use [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) in the loop, if you like to split your code into smaller pieces and into separate files.